# How to use "Adding Shared Settings" feature mentioned in the document of ESLint?

Tags: eslint, eslintrc

The [official document](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring/configuration-files#adding-shared-settings) mentions

> ESLint supports adding shared settings into configuration files. Plugins use settings to specify information that should be shared across all of its rules. You can add settings object to ESLint configuration file and it will be supplied to every rule being executed.

and gives an example for writing a shared setting:

```
{
    "settings": {
        "sharedData": "Hello"
    }
}
```

How can I use the shared settings for affecting rules? And how do the shared settings interect with the rules?